# Laravel 5.1 remove controller

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I have simple question on Laravel 5.1. I have created a controller using php artisan command:

```
php artisan make:controller PageSettings
```

However it was mistake, because I really wanted to create this controller in Admin folder like this:

```
php artisan make:controller Admin/PageSettings
```

Now I want to get rid of my old PageSettings controller. Is it ok just to delete my old PageSettings.php manualy? Or there is something more what needs to be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60370335/4650866

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you only created it and found that you did it wrong, you can manually remove the file and that's it. However when you already added routes to this controller in `routes.php` you should remove them from `routes.php` file or alter the file to reflect your new controller.

Comment: I think you also need to regenerate the composer autoload file.

Comment: so that means there is no command to remove controller via artisan?

Answer (score 8):

I had an issue with just deleting the file. I tried running my PHPUnit test suite and got an error that looked like this:

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening '/user/home/me/some/file.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /usr/home/me/some/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
```

I had to run `composer update` then `composer dump-autoload`. After that, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 7):

It is OK to manually delete controller. Just check routes.php if you have some route to that controller and delete it also.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, you can delete manually without tension.
I will suggest you for avoiding more mistakes, you "phpStrom" software, from using this, if you delete manually any file from by click right of mouse->Refactor->safe delete then before deleting they will give all places which were using your file. by clicking "do refactor" you can delete it.